# multiplicative functionals

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let G be an non-Abelian locally compact group. What is the set af all multiplicative functionals of L1(G)? (When G is abelian the answer is the dual group)

Comment: Are you looking for the dual group of the abelianization?

Comment: It is the set of all multiplicative functionals of $L^1(G)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplicative functionals on the group algebra correspond to one-dimensional unitary representations of the group. In the non-commutative case such (nontrivial) representations can be absent or constitute a small part of the set of all irreducible unitary representations. See, for example,

M. A. Naimark, Normed rings, Noordhof, Groningen, 1970.

Comment: Just to expand on the word "nontrivial" - there is of course at least one multiplicative functional on $L^1(G)$, namely the augmentation character $f\mapsto \int_G f$. The point is that there may not be any others.

Comment: (... apart from zero, obviously)